# Quicksort a list containing lists using python

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array, quicksort

If I have a list defined as such:

```
myresults = [
    [1,"A",2],
    [2,"Z",1],
    [3,"J",0]
    ]
```

and I need to sort the list. I know I can use the `sorted()` function with a key function `lambda=x:x[i]` where `i` is the position to sort in a list.  So this should work:

```
print sorted(myresults, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

and give back a list sorted on the 2nd column in the sub list.

How would you adapt a quicksort algorithm to handle a multi-dimensional list?

Comment: Isn't _that_ "multi-dimensional"?

Comment: What does this have to do with quicksort?

Comment: Which quicksort algorithm? Your own?

Comment: I wanted to see what the community had in away of quick sorts.  I only know the basic quick sort from classes.  I am looking to expand my knowledge.

Comment: `sorted` doesn't use quicksort, it uses timsort.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty solution.
If your quicksort looks like this:

```
def qsort(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = lst[0]
        lesser = qsort([x for x in lst[1:] if x < pivot])
        greater = qsort([x for x in lst[1:] if x >= pivot])
        return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

You can just use index variable to sort by required dimension:

```
def qsort_index(lst, index):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = lst[0]
        lesser = qsort_index([x for x in lst[1:] if x[index] < pivot[index]], index)
        greater = qsort_index([x for x in lst[1:] if x[index] >= pivot[index]], index)
        return lesser + [pivot] + greater



>>> qsort_index(myresults, 0)
[[1, 'A', 2], [2, 'Z', 1], [3, 'J', 0]]
>>> qsort_index(myresults, 1)
[[1, 'A', 2], [3, 'J', 0], [2, 'Z', 1]]
>>> qsort_index(myresults, 2)
[[3, 'J', 0], [2, 'Z', 1], [1, 'A', 2]]
```

This implementation is far from being optimal, but I think you got the idea.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I think there is an error in the lesser statement.

Comment: do you know how to modify this so that it sorts from biggest to smallest?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Python's [operator](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module.

```
import operator
sorted(myresults, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
[[1, 'A', 2], [2, 'Z', 1], [3, 'J', 0]]
sorted(myresults, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
[[1, 'A', 2], [3, 'J', 0], [2, 'Z', 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve with this way:

```
import operator
list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(*args))
```

and this will work too..

```
import operator
sorted(list, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```